# How can I disable a CD drive without any special software?

Tags: power-management, thinkpad, compact-disc, eject

I have a Lenovo w510 laptop. When it came, its CD drive was powered off; I right-clicked it and enabled power to it.

Now I want to power it off again, without using any software.

Does anyone know how I can disable the eject button of the CD drive?

Comment: Did you try to disable the cdrom in bios?
Did you try to disable the cdrom in hardware devices?

Or what you want to obtain is to electrically disable its opening?

Answer (score 1):

The power management settings let you decide how fast it powers off, but I'm not aware of any way to manually turn it off without involving an app or just waiting for it to go to sleep.  (I'm not even sure what you mean by "without using any software" - you want a physical switch?)

EDIT: See comments; this functionality is not native to Windows.  Requires special software.

Comment: i mean i dont want to use third party software like cd-rom eject lock. i want some setting to chnage from inside windows. if i can enable it using right click , there should be something to turn off as well

Comment: @Moorage - That right-click functionality isn't native to Windows to my knowledge; it's added by the ThinkPad power management drivers.  I don't know of any way to do what you want.

Comment: @Moorage - I can confirm 100% that I was correct and this is not Windows functionality - I just did a clean install on a ThinkPad W510 (4319-2PU if you're curious) and the power on drive functionality does NOT appear until the power management apps are installed.  Ergo, there is no way to do this built into Windows.